# Is it true that $B \leq I \rightarrow B^2 \leq I$ (or higher powers) for positive semidefinite $B$, mimicking positive scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, positivity

If we know that $B \geq 0 $  (positive semidefinite) and that  $I-B \geq 0$, is it necessarily true that $I-B^2 \geq 0$?

Comment: This looks like homework. But since $B$ has a positive square root, we can pre- and post-multiply by that square root, and obtain $B^2 \leq B$, hence $B^2 \leq I$.

Comment: Or simly note that all eigenvalues of $B$ are between 0 and 1, thus the same for $B^2$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers; did not know that I could pre- and post multiply both sides of a matrix "inequality". I think of $C<D$ as just a symbol for $C-D$ being psd. The eigenvalue argument is great too. Not homework. My inverse-problems / geophysics text says that the difference between two variance matrices is $(I-B^2)S$ (for some $S$) and that since $I-B$ is psd so is $I-B^2$. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think you can convert this (non)answer into a comment, or you can edit it into your question, provided you use the same account that you used when you asked the question.